# Invalid bucket name from docker-compose up to EC2

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

I created a docker machine on EC2.

Then I created a new [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) app and left it plain vanilla. It's set to use .env for the environment variables. (Cookiecutter-django includes [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) for accessing environment variables.)

```
docker-compose -f production.yml build
```

worked fine.

```
docker-compose -f production.yml up
```

gives this error:

```
django_1    | botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
django_1    | Invalid bucket name "": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

Researching this error, the advise was setting various environment variables. So I've tried them all in the .env (I did create an s3 bucket named pulsemanager):

```
DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=pulsemanager
AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC=pulsemanager
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=pulsemanager
```

No matter what I try I'm stuck with the error.

EDIT: It's not exactly plain vanilla. By default cookiecutter-django is using the Caddy http server instead of nginx in docker. That includes SSL and won't work behind an AWS load balancer with an AWS certificate manager SSL. So I did change the default production.yml to bring in nginx instead of Caddy, following [this article](https://msaizar.com/blog/cookiecutter-django-nginx-route-53-and-elb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a mistake in the environment filename? You wrote "evn" twice in your question when correct is ".env" https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/ .

Also, this environment variables will be available for Docker-compose file only. It means, if you need to pass this vars to particular container, you need to use `environment:` section for pass this vars to container, like this:

```
app:
  - environment:
    DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=${DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}
```

Also, you can pass all vars from the .env file, by using `env_file:` for particular container: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option

```
app:
  env_file:
    - .env
```

If you have a correct configured containers and environment variables you can debug your vars by connecting to a container and check if vars was passed.

```
docker exec -ti CONTAINER_ID /bin/export
```

Also, possible you need to add configuration to your django settings.py file. For example:

```
import os
DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=os.environ.get('DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
```

Comment: .evn was a typo. I double checked to make sure I am actually using .env.

Comment: @BradRhoads I think first, you need to be sure that your vars are passed to your containers. Please, check it as I describe above.

Comment: That was essentially the problem. Some of the settings and docs for cookiecutter_django had me confused.